# to get alphabets using number as input

Tags: perl

I'm working with some alphabet coding where input is number which returns respective alphabet . Consider input is 3 it return C, for 5 its E and so on. If number is greater than 26 output changes to AA for 27, 28-AB, 29-AC

here is the code:

```
my $input = <>;
my @a = ("A".."B");
if($input <=26){
    my $num1 = $input-1;
    say $a[$num1];
 }
 elsif( $input <= 702 ){ 
    #702 for ZZ
    my $mod = $input % 26;
    my $div = $input / 26;
    my ($letter) = $div =~ /^(\d+)\./;
    my $num1 = $div - 1;
    my $num2 = $letter - 1;
    say $a[$num1]$a[$num2];

}else{
      # Here I stuck
      # how to code for three or more letter combination?

}
```

for three letter combination any suggestions?

Update: input number can not be zero.

Comment: `$a[$div-1]a[$letter-1];` should be a syntax error... also, why are you using `$div` and `$letter` as though they were two different indexes when you know they are the same?

Comment: You're converting from base 10 to base 26 with the extra complication that you have no mapping for 0.  1 is A.  26 is Z.  27 is AA.  52 is BA.  54 is BC.  Is this what you want?

Comment: @Schewern Yes that is exactly i want. 27- AA, 28-AB... For thrree letter combination I don't know to code.

Comment: I made a mistake, 52 is AZ, 53 is BA and 54 is BB.

Comment: @TLP Code is updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a full test suite because I found this surprisingly hard to get right.

You're converting from base 10 to base 26, but since 1 is A instead of 0, everything is shifted over 1.  Dealing with that as early in the process as possible (ie. `$number--`) eliminates a lot of downstream mistakes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

my %tests = (
    1   => "A",
    1.0 => "A",
    2   => "B",
    25  => "Y",
    26  => "Z",
    27  => "AA",
    52  => "AZ",
    54  => "BB",
    78  => "BZ",
    (26**2 + 26) => "ZZ",
    (26**2 + 26 + 1) => "AAA",
    (26**3 + 26**2 + 26) => "ZZZ",
    (26**3 + 26**2 + 26 + 1) => "AAAA",
);

for my $have (keys %tests) {
    my $want = $tests{$have};
    is to_letters($have), $want, "to_letters($have) -> $want";
}

for my $negative (0, -1, -100) {
    ok !eval { to_letters($negative) }, "negative input $negative";
    like $@, qr{^0 and less cannot be converted to letters};
}

for my $decimal (1.1, 2.001) {
    ok !eval { to_letters($decimal) }, "decimal input $decimal";
    like $@, qr{^Decimals cannot be converted to letters};
}

done_testing;

use Carp;

sub to_letters {
    my $number = shift;
    croak "0 and less cannot be converted to letters" if $number <= 0;
    croak "Decimals cannot be converted to letters" if int $number != $number;

    state $BASE = 26;
    state $CHAR_BASE = 65;

    my @letters;
    while( $number > 0 ) {
        $number--;  # A is 1, not 0
        my $shift = $number % $BASE;
        unshift @letters, chr( $CHAR_BASE + $shift );
        $number = int($number / $BASE);
    }

    return join '', @letters;
}
```

The constants might seem silly, but it's the 21st century and there's a very good chance other character encodings will be a consideration.  Although I doubt `chr( $CHAR_BASE + $shift)` will work out as neatly.

Comment: Yes, I've also been getting caught out by the edge cases on the `while` loop. Straight modulo/divide approach falls apart on some of the zeros.

Comment: What is the role of $CHAR_BASE variable here? Why it have value 65?

Comment: @wagh It takes advantage of an attribute of [the ASCII table](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ascii+table) where A-Z are contiguous starting with A at 65.  This also works for UTF-8 since it shares the first 127 characters with ASCII.  It doesn't work with much else.  For other alphabets you'd make your own table using an array like `@letter_map = ("A", "B", "C", "Ç", "D".."G", "Ğ", "H", "I", "İ", and so on...);` and reference it with `$letter_map[$shift];`  Using chr is a hold over from C to save a few bytes of memory, the array table is likely just as efficient and more flexible.

Comment: this is easy to get right:  `$result = "A"; ++$result while --$input > 0;`  (but don't do that...)

Comment: @ysth I considered using that for the tests, I was getting so confused about the roll over points.

Comment: To remove all the constants and gain maximum flexibility, you'd have the user pass in a number and a list of letters to map things to.  `num_to_chars(54, ["A".."Z"])`.  `$BASE` would be the length of the letter list.  For convenience, you could put a wrapper around the common character sets.  `sub num_to_uc_ascii { state $chars = ["A".."Z"]; return num_to_chars(shift, $chars); }`

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a while loop. Not sure where you got 351 though - I get that as "NN". 26 * 26 = 676.

E.g. something like:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $number = 17577;
my @letters;

while ( $number > 0 ) {
  my $part = $number % 26; 
  #print "$part, $number\n";

  $number -= $part;

  if ( $number == 26 ) { $number = 0; }
  $number /= 26;
  #print "$number $part\n";
  push @letters,chr(65+$part);
}

print reverse @letters;
```

Comment: Pls explain why 65 is used? `@letters,chr(65+$part);`

Comment: ASCII codes start at 65, which is 'A'. That's doing the same as your array mapping, but without needing an array for it. If it makes it clearer, you could do `chr ( ord("A") + $part );`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Perl well enough to write the answer in it, but here's an algorithm that will work for any length:

```
verify the input value is valid for your purpose
set Number to the input value (for clarity in this answer, or if you need the input value later)
set Output to an empty string
while Number > 25
   set Remainder to Number modulo 26 plus 1
   set Number to the integer part of Number divided by 26
   prepend the character represented by Remainder to Output
end while

if Number is not zero prepend the character represented by Number plus 1 to the Output
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl already does alphabetical auto-incrementing, so the shortest way to achieve what you want is to exploit that in a loop.

```
my $a = 'A';
my $n = $ARGV[0];
for (my $i = 1; $i < $n; $i++) { $a++ }
print $a;
```

Of course, the larger the number, the more loops, so it may not be efficient for extremely large numbers.